# How can I assign the value from the slider to a variable? I can only use .get() to print the output, not store it

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, slider

I need it to store the value of the slider in a variable, say `v` when the button is clicked. For context, I need this so I can have a slider that sets the starting amount of money for my poker game A level project.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

def show_values():
    print (w.get()) #would I put it in this function?

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 700, height = 200, bg = "blue")
w = Scale(root,from_=0, to=200,length = 200, orient=HORIZONTAL,bg = "green")
Button(root, text='Show', command=show_values).pack() 
w.pack()
canvas.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to store multiple values or a single value on every click of the button?

Comment: just the single value of the click of that button. So if they slide to 100, then click the button, 100 will be stored. If they change their mind they can then slide it and just click the button again and it replaces the old value with the new value

Comment: Then I don't see a point in saving the value to another variable as the value can be used directly from `w.get()` if it is globally assigned.

Comment: I need it to be able to be used anywhere in the program and it also needs to be able to be edited. When I do anything like v = w.get() it says v = 0 no matter what the slider is on. Is there any way to make v the value of the slider, as I am going to use it lots in this code

Comment: why can't you use `w.get()` instead of `v`? Like use `w.get()` everywhere in your code.

Comment: I think ill probably just do that yea though I thought it would be easier to have it as a variable that can easily be altered. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you were setting v in the body of the GUI definition.  It needs to be set in the relevant button's command function.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

v = 0 
def set_value():    
    global v
    v = w.get()  # v is set here

def do_print():
    print( v )   # v can be read here.

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 700, height = 200, bg = "blue")
w = Scale(root,from_=0, to=200,length = 200, orient=HORIZONTAL,bg = "green")
Button(root, text='Set', command=set_value).pack()     
Button(root, text='Print', command = do_print).pack() 
w.pack()
canvas.pack()

mainloop()
```

The 'Set' Button sets the value of v which can be read by clicking the 'Print' Button.

Comment: Isn't `global` generally a bad practice, especially for beginners? Especially since python is an OOP language?

Comment: @Богдан-Опир I agree but to simply show what's happening here I think it's clearer.  All the other elements in this GUI are global too.

Comment: I'm not doing my code in OOP, but the point of v is just a variable which the user uses to set the amount of chips the player starts with. I wanted it to be a variable because it would be easier to edit, copy and manipulate throughout the game.